# glslLangValidator multiple preprocessor substitutions

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, preprocessor, vulkan

I want to access uniform block instance members using macros like in the following shader:

```
#version 450 core

layout(std140, set=0, binding=0) uniform UBlock {
    float value;
} uInstance;
#define value uInstance.value

#define saturate(X) clamp( X, 0, 1 )

layout(location = 0) out float Out;

void main ()
{
    Out = value;
    Out = saturate(value);
}
```

but whenever i pass the redefined symbol to another macro, glsllangValidator returns the following error:

```
ERROR: D:/shader_translation/glsl_preprocessor.frag:15: 'uInstance' : no such field in structure
ERROR: D:/shader_translation/glsl_preprocessor.frag:15: '' : compilation terminated
ERROR: 2 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

Is there a way to make this work?
it works with cpp:
(https://onlinegdb.com/SJ-B3A8tP)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is how macros work in glsl. By defining `value` as `uInstance.value`, the GLSL preprocessor will also replace the value in `uInstance.value`, resulting in `uInstance.uinstance.value`. That's what the error message is referring too.

If you e.g. change the shader to

```
#version 450 core

layout(std140, set=0, binding=0) uniform UBlock {
    float value;
} uInstance;

#define val uInstance.value

#define saturate(X) clamp( X, 0, 1 )

layout(location = 0) out float Out;

void main ()
{
    Out = val;
    Out = saturate(val);
}
```

It compiles fine with the Vulkan target environment.

Comment: thx, it seems there is no way to accomplish what i need then. The error occurs on the second line, where the macro is given to another macro, first line works well. I though there might be a way to circumvent the second expansion on the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` variable is accessible from outside the `uInstance` struct without having to specify `uInstance.*`. That is - you don't have to #define, you just use `value`. It also seems to be interfering with the #define as if you rename it - it works fine(at least for me).

Comment: unfortunately i need the instance for reflection purposes...

Comment: As i said, renaming #define to be different from the name of variable works fine

Comment: with which compiler can you access the value member without any define? im using latest vulkan sdk and directly using value results in an undeclared identifer error. i cant change the #define name

Comment: I am using glslc